# Javascript inheritance with prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I googled 1 hour but couldn't find a good answer. So here is my question: How can I inherit a class with its prototypes?

I have currently this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RdxYN/2/

```
function BaseContent(a, b) {
    this.propertyA = 'propertyA';
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    alert('x');
}

BaseContent.prototype.funcA = function () {
    alert(this.a + ', ' + this.b);
    alert(this.propertyA);
};

function ContentA(a, b) {
    BaseContent.call(this, a, b);
    this.funcA();
}

ContentA.prototype = new BaseContent;
ContentA.prototype.constructor = ContentA;
ContentA.prototype.parent = BaseContent.prototype;

var Content = new ContentA('c', 'd');
```

The only problem is, is that BaseContent is executed twice. I don't want that. Is there a better solution or a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new way to achieve inheritance in JavaScript is to use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) as follows:

```
function BaseContent(a, b) {
    this.propertyA = 'propertyA';
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    alert('x');
}

BaseContent.prototype.funcA = function () {
    alert(this.a + ', ' + this.b);
    alert(this.propertyA);
};

function ContentA(a, b) {
    BaseContent.call(this, a, b);
    this.funcA();
}

ContentA.prototype = Object.create(BaseContent.prototype);
ContentA.prototype.constructor = ContentA;
ContentA.prototype.parent = BaseContent.prototype;

var Content = new ContentA('c', 'd');
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RdxYN/7/

You should probably read my blog post on [Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/) to gain a deeper understanding of inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: To the OP -- this is available on modern browsers (EcmaScript 5 standard), but not e.g. IE 8.

Comment: @Will Hm okay, thats not a big problem. But it would be nice, if there is a solution for IE8.

Comment: @user2820280 Just add the following code to the beginning of your program and it'll work in every browser: `if (!Object.create) Object.create = (function (Factory) { return function (prototype) { Factory.prototype = prototype; return new Factory; }; }(function () {}));`

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to set it up more like this

```
function BaseContent(a, b) {
    this.propertyA = 'propertyA';
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    alert('x');
}

BaseContent.prototype = {
    funcA: function () {
        alert(this.a + ', ' + this.b);
        alert(this.propertyA);
    }
};

function ContentA(a, b) {
    BaseContent.call(this, a, b);
    this.funcA();
}

ContentA.prototype = BaseContent.prototype;
ContentA.prototype.constructor = ContentA;

var Content = new ContentA('c', 'd');
```

Here is the example is JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LD8PX/

Answer (score 1):

For IE 7/8 compatible, you can refer to the [Simple javascript inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHUFD/

```
var BaseContent = Class.extend({
    init: function (a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.propertyA = 'propertyA';
        alert('x');
    },
    funcA: function () {
        alert(this.a + ', ' + this.b);
        alert(this.propertyA);
    }
}); 

var ContentA = BaseContent.extend({
    init: function (a, b) {
        this._super(a, b);
        this.funcA();
    }
}); 

var Content = new ContentA('c', 'd');
```